# Are there slot machines with wheels that use bingo internally?

Tags: united-states, gambling

I've heard rumors that many slot machines use an invisible internal bingo algorithm to determine whether they pay out, supposedly as a way around [the Indian Gaming Regulatory Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Gaming_Regulatory_Act#Class_II).

For example, I found this [on one site (with a rather clickbait looking title)](https://www.gamblingsites.com/blog/19-facts-about-gambling-machines-that-will-surprise-your-friends-16390/), and also [a](http://blog.al.com/spotnews/2012/12/victorylands_gambing_machines.html) [few](http://blog.al.com/spotnews/2012/12/victorylands_gambing_machines.html) [other](http://www.slot-source.com/advanced-slot-topics/how-bingo-slot-machines-work/) [examples](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g51690-d940161-r77608946-WinStar_World_Casino_and_Resort-Thackerville_Oklahoma.html#REVIEWS) which claim that you will have spinning wheels and bingo running on the same machine.

One in particular makes this claim:

> Whereas Class III machines operate in a independent manner, Class II machines are really just an elaborate display for the bingo games running in the background. When you hit the spin button, you enter into a game of bingo. Like real games of bingo, Class II games require at least two players. If you’re at a small casino that’s not busy, the reels may spin for an abnormally long time while it waits for someone else to join the game.

I've seen video bingo machines in casinos, but it **sounds like** there are standard slot machines that operate as follows:

- The gambler inserts money, pulls a lever
- Wheels start spinning
- Internally, the machine plays a game of bingo on an embedded computer
- Depending on the outcome of the internal bingo game, the wheels stop "randomly" on predetermined symbols

So far, though, I haven't been able to find any solid sources that explain or verify this. Is this picture approximately correct, and are there solid sources?

Comment: You've taken the claim: "In *some* states, *video poker* games are based on bingo, and are called Class II." and transformed it into "The *wheels* on a *slot machine* are controlled by a bingo game." The opening section explains video poker machines don't have wheels, so this is confused.

Comment: Note: Class II machines are based on bingo [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Gaming_Regulatory_Act#Class_II), so asking if Class II machines are based on bingo is kind of tautological.

Comment: I guess I was looking for an example of such a machine. I've changed the title to reflect this. I could imagine that they all might just be a touch screen that lets you play bingo.

Comment: Do slot machines even have wheels any more?

Comment: You are looking for an example of a Class II *slot machine* when the claim is about Class II *video poker* machines.

Comment: @jamesqf Some do, but they're controlled by a computer to present the result that electronic algorithm determined.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, this is exactly my question: are there concrete examples of machines that use bingo for this algorithm?

Comment: @Shep: Your own link explains the difference: Slot machines: "has spinning reels with symbols on them." Video Poker games: "doesn’t have spinning reels." Some video poker games are bingo based: "But in some states, you’ll find games that look like video poker games but are actually bingo games in disguise." IT DOES NOT SAY spinning reel slot machines are bingo based. It says some video poker games WITHOUT WHEELS are bingo based. Your title does not match the claim.

Comment: I did say "for example". It's not the only example. Look here: http://blog.al.com/spotnews/2012/12/victorylands_gambing_machines.html, http://www.slot-source.com/advanced-slot-topics/how-bingo-slot-machines-work/

Comment: Also edited the question to include these examples. @Oddthinking, what do I need to do to reopen this? I think the title and claim match now.

Comment: I had a chat with an expert a US gaming law and he made similar claims, which convinced me that it is notable. Unfortunately this is unreferenceable here, and I feel very guilty about waving my hands and saying "Yes, this is notable. Trust me." I hope you'll forgive me. (Note: I am NOT using him as an answer reference! That would be going too far.)

Comment: That's ok. But how what's this about things being "notable"? I thought you were dismissing the claim on the grounds that it _wasn't_ well sourced. Anyway, thanks for un-closing.

Comment: It is probably not relevant but as I understand it very very old mechanical "one arm bandits" utilise a form of mechanical type clock / timer to base payouts on. If this is to induce a random element or to perform other functions too I could not say. I say this after looking at several a few months ago in EBay to simply see how they worked from the pictures as some of those "how it works" sites are rather vague in detail of the say 60s to 70s "non electrical mechanical only" machines.